# Variants of maximal functions by taking square roots

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Question: Prove or disprove the following; Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be locally integrable and for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ define
$$h(x) = \limsup_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|^{1/2} dy.$$
Then $|f(x)| \leq h(x)^2$ a.e.

My attempt: I believe this statement is true since given that $f$ is locally integrable then $|f|^{1/2}$ is also locally integrable by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. By Lebesgue differentiation theorem $|f(x)|^{1/2} = h(x)$ for a.e $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and so $|f(x)| = h(x)^2$ and the inequality is satisfied.

Is this proof satisfactory for this question or are there any counterexamples for this problem? Any hints or solutions are appreciated.